# How to sac goblins to Skirk Prospector quickly?

Tags: magic-the-gathering-arena

For FNM, I played a historic goblins deck with a [Skirk Prospector](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=443032) in it.

During a mirror match, an opponent was able to sacrifice goblins to his Skirk Prospector instantly.  I had to click the prospector, click on a goblin, click on "submit 1", 4 separate times.  i.e. very slow.  Are there keyboard short cuts for making this happen more quickly?  How was he able to do this so quickly?

Comment: Do you have the automatic game settings enabled?

Comment: Yes I did......

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing you can do to actually "instantly" activate Skirk Prospector, but there is something you can do to make it *appear to your opponent* that you are doing so.

If you drag your spell out over the battlefield to cast it when you need mana from Prospector to actually do so, the interface will first tap all of your lands and then prompt you to choose goblins to sacrifice to pay the remaining cost. You will still need to click a goblin and click "Submit 1" as many times as necessary.

However, the opponent doesn't see any of these intermediate steps. Rather, when you're finally done casting the spell, they will see all of your lands tap and all of your chosen goblins disappear all at the same time.